# RegEx: How to match a substring but to exclude some strings?

Tags: .net, regex

I have this text:

```
assessment requirementassessment cevaassessment cevaassessmentfdsfsd fdsjfkdsf fsdjfsdkj
```

I want as a result this:

```
assessment cevaassessment cevaassessmentfdsfsd
```

In other words I want to match all assessment containing words but after that to exclude requirementassessment words.

How to do that with Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage a negative lookbehind to accomplish this:

```
\w*(?<!requirement)assessment\w*
```

<sup>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/92lPfI/2)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
\w*(?<!requirement)assessment\w*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qFZ3q4/5)

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output in the question